# Strange Error with MySQL Prepared Statement

Tags: mysql, jdbc

My prepared statement is

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1=?) tempTable WHERE column2='test'
```

When I execute this statement in MySQL standard cli, it works;
but when I use jdbc to execute this state I get the following error message:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'tms.tempTable' doesn't exist

Could anybody give some helps?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `select * from (select * from table1 where column1=?) as tempTable where column2='test' `?

Comment: This is a subquery alias, not a table, so it's should always exist, or cant execute in cli either.

Comment: And yes i have tried with as key word, the same problem shows!

Comment: Have you tried the statemend on mysql console?

Comment: yes i try this state in console with prepare and all worked fine, but when move this statement to jdbc, got the error

Comment: Can you add more code ?

Comment: Please show the Java code where you prepare the statement and execute it

Comment: In java code I use the code:    jdbcT.queryForRowSet(sql, params, types);

Comment: And from the mysql operation log, i got the following output: 316 Query select * from ( 
SELECT *  
FROM   Table
) tempTable
    316 Query SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `tms`.`tempTable`
    316 Query SELECT 1